# Asp.net MVC preview page before save and highlight the modified model properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to redirect to the preview page from edit page and highlight the modified text when the preview button is clicked in "edit" page. In preview page we have a save button to save in the database.

How to implement this feature.

Comment: you can retrieve your object populate before edit from database to a ViewBag and compare 2 objects inside your foreach

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
       @{
          string _style  = string.Empty;
          for(int i=0;i<Model.Count;i++){
            _style = "none"  ;
            var listEdited = ((List<CastYourTypeObject>)ViewBag.ObjectEdited);
            if(Model[i] == listEdited[i]){
             _style = "highlight";  
            }
                <tr>
                  <td class="@_style">@Html.Display(objAttribute)</td>
                </tr>
          }
        }
```